# Spam only user might need some banning

Tags: discussion

I have seen 2 questions closed by this user today, but the user is still here (currently no actual questions anymore, they were all spammed)

https://askubuntu.com/users/156017/ahmed-molvi

I suppose the user might deserve some attention?

Comment: I got same too, but more, about 5(?), even s/he uses unregistered username (user******)

Answer (score 3):

The spam user has since been deleted. I suppose it isn't worth our time to go through the user suspension process for an obvious spammer.